# Iron:router Never Returns Defined Collection (version 1.0.12)

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

For some reason, my `data: function...` always returns as `undefined`.

Here's my server code:

```
Flyers = new Mongo.Collection('flyers');

Meteor.publish('flyers', function() {
  return Flyers.find({});
});
```

As simple as it gets.

Here's my routes file (which is in a directory called `both`):

```
Router.route('/dashboard', {
  template: 'dashboard',
  layoutTemplate: "dashboardLayout",
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('flyers');
  },
  data: function() {
    return Flyers.find()
  }
 });
```

Only to see:

[image]

Any reason this isn't working?

Comment: `Flyers = new Mongo.Collection('flyers');` needs to be defined in a `lib` folder, so it's available on the client and server side.

Comment: @BrianShamblen that's the right answer, you should make it an answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `Flyers` variable is defined with your server code, it will only be accessible on the server. Attempting to access this variable on the client side will result in an `undefined` value, because it doesn't exist.

Common code that's needed on both the client and server should be defined in a `lib` folder to make it accessible in both places.

On a side note, the reason for this is that in some cases you may want collections to be accessible on only the client, or only the server, but not both.